# Solidworks Flow Simulation the Rotation option missing

Tags: finite-element-method, simulation, solidworks

I am looking for assistance to understand why, with SolidWorks 2017, in the "Flow Simulation wizard - Analysis Type" I have no "Rotation" option?

What do I need to do in order to see it?.

The "Rotating Region" is not active, it is a gray icon in "Command Manager".

[wizard - Analysis Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9g16.png)

[Rotating Region" is not active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YttVN.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your unit system and parameters are properly defined (you'll want "SI"), you have saved your file, and also that you have selected the object(s) before clicking the wizard. If this doesn't work, save your file and restart SolidWorks (it may be a glitch).

a quick search on Youtube shows a video of exactly what you want:
[Youtube Tutorial: Solidworks Rotation Simulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwX7bJXSP5Q)